# content not allowed in prolog, error in deskop.ini file

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I have the folder of my android app placed in google drive. Some days ago I deleted the file deskop.ini on the main folder of google drive because I thought it was harmless.

Every time I try to execute the my android app i get the following error:

> Error:The content is not allowed in the prolog.
>   C:\Users\Alvaro\Google Drive\Android Studio
>   Projects\MySecurity1\app\src\main\res\values\desktop.ini Error:Error:
>   The content is not allowed in the prolog. :app:mergeDebugResources
>   FAILED Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
> > C:\Users\Alvaro\Google Drive\Morosof\AppSecurity\Android Studio Projects\MySecurity1\app\src\main\res\values\desktop.ini:0:0: Error:
> >     The content is not allowed in the prolog.

I've put back the file deskop.ini from the bin, but with no results.

If I open the file deskop.ini placed in the folder \res\values this is the code in it:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
InfoTip=This file has been shared online.
IconFile=C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Drive\googledrivesync.exe
IconIndex=12
```

If I delete the file and try to rebuild the project I get error in parsing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by just deleting all the deskop.ini in the whole project! This files aren't related to the project, they are automatically created by google drive and they just create errors in the project because the IDE doesn't understand them!